# How to rostest a single (entire) package in catkin workspace?

Tags: catkin, rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(I believe related to http://answers.ros.org/question/62583/how-do-i-only-run-tests-for-only-one-package/)

I have found through painful trial-and-error that when `rostests` are defined in a package's CMakeLists.txt, they will not build with the typical `catkin_make run_tests_<package>`:

- `catkin_make run_tests` **WORKS**
- `catkin_make run_tests_<package>` **DOESN'T WORK**

It is quite painful to not have the ability to run `rostests` from only one package at a time.
Is this expected behavior, and can anyone explain why?

*hydro on 12.04*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196629/how-to-rostest-a-single-(entire)-package-in-catkin-workspace?/) by [dsolomon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2369/dsolomon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you referring to the **compilation** of your test executables, or the running of those tests? The build process separates these things into two separate build steps, with associated build targets.

The relevant build targets:

- `tests`: Builds all of the test nodes. Does not run them.
- `run_tests_<package>`: Runs the tests for a specific package. Does not build them.
- `run_tests`: Depends on the `tests` target and all of the `run_tests_<package>` targets in the current workspace. Building this target causes all of the tests to be built and run.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-04**:
Also: be sure that `CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING` is defined when building your workspace. Properly written `CMakeLists.txt` should not setup any test-related targets if `CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING` is not defined. A normal `catkin_make` invocation should have that defined, but I thought I'd mention it.

**Comment by [dsolomon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2369/dsolomon/) on 2015-02-12**:
Don't know why I just saw this, but thanks guys! Is this behavior from cmake or catkin? And is there a any human-readable source for this information? Reading cmake documentation feels like reading the Rosetta stone: it only makes sense after you already figured it out.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-02-13**:
These targets are created by the test functions that come from rostest and catkin. I don't remember where to find the documentation anymore.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-02-13**:
From the catkin howto: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/run_tests.html